# add class to submit button if form is valid

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Im using the jQuery validate plugin to validate a form, im wanting to add a class "next" to the submit button if the form is valid only

Send

This is the code i have at the moment all working and validating, just need a function to add the class if valid:
http://jsfiddle.net/kKSjL/

Link to jQuery validation page:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of code in the question rather than as external links. What happens if the external page gets deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archer has it generally, you just need to specify that as a `submitHandler` within the validate call:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
    submitHandler:function(form){
        if (this.valid()){
          $('#submit').addClass('next');
          form.submit();
        } 
    }  
});
```

Here it is in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/kKSjL/1/

Answer (score 0):

However you're triggering the validation check, you need this code...

```
if ($("#commentForm").valid()) {
    $("#submit").addClass("next");
} else {
    $("#submit").removeClass("next");
}
```

Comment: thanks, Ryley's worked a tread on jsfiddle so i used that, but appreciate you taking the time to answer my question

Comment: No problem - glad you got it sorted :)